Best way to handle multiple exit points in Fortran
I have a Fortran code which reads a file (if you're curious about the background, see How to safely check whether a Fortran file exists when reading it with Python?). Since this code is called from Python, I need to handle all or most IO errors because I don't want my Python code to crash without a sensible error message. I thus edited the Fortran code this way:
  subroutine read_params(filename, params, ierr)
  implicit none
  ! Argument Declarations !
  character(len=*), intent(in) :: filename
  integer, dimension(4), intent(out) :: params
  integer, intent(out) :: ierr
  ! Variable Declarations
  integer :: i, iounit, ios
  character(len=:), allocatable :: errmsg

  iounit = 1
  ierr = 0 ! Initialize error code
  allocate(character(len=256+len(filename)) :: errmsg)
  open(unit=iounit, status="old", file=filename, form="unformatted", iostat=ios, iomsg=errmsg)
  call check_for_io_errors(ios, "open", ierr, errmsg)
  if (ierr /= 0) then
      close(iounit)
      return
  end if
  read(iounit, *, iostat=ios, iomsg=errmsg) (params(i), i=1, 4)
  call check_for_io_errors(ios, "read", ierr, errmsg)
  if (ierr /= 0) then
      close(iounit)
      return
  end if
  close(iounit)

  end subroutine read_params

As you can see, the subroutine has multiple exit points, and some code duplication. Alternatively, I could do
      subroutine read_params(filename, params, ierr)
      implicit none
      ! Argument Declarations !
      character(len=*), intent(in) :: filename
      integer, dimension(4), intent(out) :: params
      integer, intent(out) :: ierr
      ! Variable Declarations
      integer :: i, iounit, ios
      character(len=:), allocatable :: errmsg

      iounit = 1
      ierr = 0 ! Initialize error code
      allocate(character(len=256+len(filename)) :: errmsg)
      open(unit=iounit, status="old", file=filename, form="unformatted", iostat=ios, iomsg=errmsg)
      call check_for_io_errors(ios, "open", ierr, errmsg)
      if (ierr /= 0) then
          goto 10
      end if
      read(iounit, *, iostat=ios, iomsg=errmsg) (params(i), i=1, 4)
      call check_for_io_errors(ios, "read", ierr, errmsg)
      if (ierr /= 0) then
          goto 10
      end if
10    close(iounit)

      end subroutine read_params

which uses the dreaded goto statement. What is the preferred way to do this in Fortran ≤ 2003? Also, if you have any other suggestions to improve the code, feel free to let me know.
PS it's probably not necessary to answer the main question, but here is the source for the subroutine check_for_io_errors in case you're curious:
  subroutine check_for_io_errors(ios, operation, ierr, errmsg)
  implicit none
  ! Argument Declarations !
  integer, intent(in) :: ios
  character(len=*), intent(in) :: operation
  integer, intent(out) :: ierr
  character(len=*), intent(in) :: errmsg

  if (ios /= 0) then
      if (operation == "open") then
          ierr = -1
          print *, "Error opening file"
          print *, "Error message: " // trim(errmsg)
      else if (operation == "read") then
          ierr = -2
          print *, "Error reading file"
          print *, "Error message: " // trim(errmsg)
      else if (operation == "write") then
          ierr = -3
          print *, "Error writing file"
          print *, "Error message: " // trim(errmsg)
      end if
  end if

  end subroutine check


Matter of style so I won't be surprised if this gets closed as opinion based ... If pushed and threatened with violence to force me to chose one of the above I would use the return method but don't strongly prefer one over the other. But if left to my own devices I would probably split the open, read (and close) operations into their own routines in some kind of I/O module or type

@IanBush splitting each operation into a separate routine sounds me a bit like overengineering. I'd rather not write a lot of code for something which seems to me a simple task, in the end (read a few parameters from a binary file). However, that could also be an irrational reaction on my end (writing Fortran code makes my hair stand on end). If you can write an answer that shows what you mean and improves the existing code without overcomplicating things, I'd gladly accept it.

Maybe later. But I don't really think there's a "right" answer; do whatever you yourself feel happiest with is what I ultimately think.

There are many options, including for example like with this other question. As suggested, probably a matter of style more than anything else.

Should've thought of Block. I'm pretty sure Alternate Return has been deleted from the language, so no need to frighten the children with that.

@francescalus it looks like block was introduced in Fortran 2008, so I'm not sure I can use it, but I'll try

@IanBush understood. Anyway, if you decide to take a stab at it later, I'll be happy to read your attempt.

print * - bad idea (or very difficult). Fortran and Python, each independently, buffer the output.

Reasonnable uses of goto, like here, look fine to me. The advantage compared to the return solution is that you don't have to repeat the close(iounit) statement (ok, it's just one statement, but imagine if you have several of them...).
As noted in the comments, the block control structure offers a maybe more structured way:
block
   ...
   if (ierr /= 0) exit
   ...
   if (ierr /= 0) exit
   ...
end block
close(iounit)

If your compiler doesn't allow using it, you can achieve something similar with an "infinite do loop" (just don't forget the final exit!):
do
   ...
   if (ierr /= 0) exit
   ...
   if (ierr /= 0) exit
   ...
   exit
end do
close(iounit)


Probably, shortes code (ios == 0 - OK):
subroutine read_params(filename, params, ios)
   implicit none
   ! Argument Declarations !
   character(len=*), intent(in) :: filename
   integer, dimension(4), intent(out) :: params
   integer, intent(out) :: ios
   ! Variable Declarations
   integer :: i, iounit

   iounit = 1
   open(unit=iounit, status="old", file=filename, form="unformatted", &
        err=10, iostat=ios)
   read(iounit, *, err=10, iostat=ios) (params(i), i=1, 4)
10 close(iounit)

end subroutine read_params

Mix python&fortran output to stdout - bad idea (need nonstandard flush, etc, unstable). If necessary, you can add out argument errmsg for printing in python code.
subroutine read_params_msg(filename, params, ios, errmsg)
   implicit none
   ! Argument Declarations !
   character(len=*), intent(in) :: filename
   integer, dimension(4), intent(out) :: params
   integer, intent(out) :: ios
   character(len=256), intent(out) :: errmsg
   ! Variable Declarations
   integer :: i, iounit

   iounit = 1
   errmsg = ""
   open(unit=iounit, status="old", file=filename, form="unformatted", &
        err=10, iostat=ios, iomsg=errmsg)
   read(iounit, *, err=10, iostat=ios, iomsg=errmsg) (params(i), i=1, 4)
10 close(iounit)

end subroutine read_params_msg

Open in Colab
P.S.
IMHO, from the point of view of reliable programming, the use of open(..., iostat=<var>) is undesirable, since it requires constant verification (human review, automatic fortran lint) of the presence of analysis of the variable var.
open(..., [iostat=<var>,] err=<label>) is, of course, worse than error handling with exceptions in other languages, but the main thing is that in case of an error, control is not transferred to the next operator. I.e., the behavior of open(...) it's not getting worse. If the error is open(...) the program terminate, and if the error is open(..., err=<label>), the program goes to the label.
